# Calculate work days

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to calculate work days between two dates. `NETWORKDAYS` will do the trick, however I am having difficulty structuring the `IF` statement components.

I have 5 columns, Column A will always have a start date; the other 4 columns might not. What I want to calculate is the network days between Column A and B, but if B is blank then Column A and C, and if C is blank, then Column A and D and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(A1<>"",NETWORKDAYS(A1, B1), IF(C1<>"", NETWORKDAYS(A1, C1)))`

This does the trick, I could not get `AGGREGATE/INDEX`to work

Answer (score 4):

Use this formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A1,INDEX(A1:E1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B1:E1)/(B1:E1<>""),1)))
```

The INDEX/AGGREGATE will find the first cell in B:E that is not empty and return that as the end date to the NETWORKDAYS.

[image]

Comment: that looks like it would do exactly what I need, but when I put in the formula I get a reference error

Comment: What excel are you using?

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` in your formulas?  Are your dates true dates and not text that look like dates?  There are many many reasons the formula will not work.  Look at your data and at the method in which you enter formulas.